# Node.JS - common project location

Tags: node.js

On a Linux machine, where are Node.JS projects commonly kept?  For example, if I wrote a custom one where should I keep it such that another Node.JS programmer coming onto the system would likely look there first to find it?

I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/recommended-location-of-node-js-applications-in-linux-filesystem which suggests `/srv`, but I wasn't sure if that was just the "technically correct" location based on the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, or if that was actually where people tend to keep projects.

This is assuming it's not a project written by a limited-rights user on the system (i.e. in which case I'm guessing the odds increase that it'd live in that user's home folder).

Comment: I think this is opinion based, but I use `/srv/projectName`. I've also seen `/data`, `/projectName`, `/var/www`, `/opt/www`, and `/web`, which I dislike in increasing order. I don't mind it being I'm the home dir of user that has read permissions only for the node related and no other filesystem permissions.

Comment: For general code safety reasons, I prefer that my server does not run with root privileges.  As such, I create a user for it and put the server in that user's home folder.